# Why the ANTLR rules accept 'abc123' as a number?

Tags: antlr

I try to use ANTLR to construct a very simple rules as following:

```
number :
  INT
  ;

INT : '0'..'9'+
  ;
```

It would accept `123` as `number`, but I am not sure why it also accepts `abc123` as `number`?

How can I correct the rules to parse `number`?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I am not sure why it also accepts abc123 as number?

It doesn't.

Perhaps you're using some 3<sup>rd</sup> party tool/editor in which it is difficult to see the error message(s) printed to the console, but they're there. The parser is probably just recovering from the mismatched input making it **look like** `INT` accepts input like `"abc123"`.

Comment: Hi Bart, yes, I used the Eclipse plugin, ANTLR IDE, to test. I tried ANTLRWorks, it showed different result. I may need to find another antlr plugin for Eclipse. Thanks!